# Resgatar somente 10 primeiros registros de objeto Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou enroscado em uma parte do código que estou fazendo. Preciso resgatar somente os 10 primeiros registros de um objeto que chamo em um laço for:

```
listaTabela = []
        for aluno in alunos:
            listaLinha = ""
            listaLinha += str(aluno.getRA())
            listaLinha += ";"
            listaLinha += str(aluno.getNome())

            listaTabela.append(listaLinha)
```

Do jeito que está, ele faz o laço for normalmente enquanto houver registros em 'alunos'. Teria uma maneira de limitar este laço para que ele execute somente nos 10 primeiros registros? Tentei usando while mas ele repetiu o mesmo registro 10 vezes.

Comment: Sérgio, se puderes corrige a indentação...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente fatiar sua lista de alunos assim:

```
listaTabela = []

for aluno in alunos[:10]:
    listaLinha = ""
    listaLinha += str(aluno.getRA())
    listaLinha += ";"
    listaLinha += str(aluno.getNome())

    listaTabela.append(listaLinha)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago, era isso mesmo que eu queria! Procurei por este tipo de manipulação mas não encontrei em outro lugares, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Obrigado JJoao. Corrigido.

Answer (score 6):

No seu exemplo específico, utilizar a sintaxe indicada pelo @ThiagoLuizS é a melhor alternativa mesmo. Eu apenas gostaria de ressaltar que nem todos os objetos iteráveis são "fatiáveis". Por exemplo, isto pode ser iterado:

```
for i in map(int, '12345'):
    print(i)
```

Mas não pode ser fatiado:

```
map(int, '12345')[1:] # TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Para estes objetos, use o `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import islice
for i in islice(map(int, '12345'), 1, 5):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Cool (+1). Alternativamente `list(map(int, '12345'))[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

Se o teu  Python for recente, tenta usar listas em compreensão e f-strings:

```
tab=[f'Nome: {x.getNome()}; {x.getRA()}' for x in alunos[:10]]
```